# parse error in spring-elasticsearch.xsd

Tags: spring, spring-data

I'm trying to use the spring data elasticsearch module, but I get a parse error in spring-elasticsearch.xsd when defining my beans.

the namespace declaration looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:elasticsearch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch.xsd">
```

and I get this parse error:

```
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@795ee430] to prepare test instance [no.di.scheduler.ElasticSearchLoaderTest@44d74990]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:105)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 40 in XML document from class path resource [dao-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch.xsd; lineNumber: 40; columnNumber: 116; s4s-att-invalid-value: Invalid attribute value for 'source' in element 'documentation': cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch/spring-elasticsearch.xsd; lineNumber: 40; columnNumber: 116; s4s-att-invalid-value: Invalid attribute value for 'source' in element 'documentation': cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:267)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:201)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 49 more
```

If I download the document and remove the source attribute from the  tags it works as expected.

Is this due to that I still use spring 3.2, or is there some other error that i'm doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to @Chris White.

In my case, I've stored the xsd file in META-INF.

1) Download de elasticsearch-1.0.xsd and fix it properly.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:tool="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool" xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository" targetNamespace="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"/>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool"/>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository" schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd"/>
    <xsd:element name="repositories">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexContent>
                <xsd:extension base="repository:repositories">
                    <xsd:attributeGroup ref="repository:repository-attributes"/>
                    <xsd:attribute name="elasticsearch-template-ref" type="elasticsearchTemplateRef" default="elasticsearchTemplate"/>
                </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:complexContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:simpleType name="elasticsearchTemplateRef">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
                <tool:annotation kind="ref">
                    <tool:assignable-to type="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate"/>
                </tool:annotation>
            </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:element name="node-client">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation />
            <xsd:appinfo>
                <tool:assignable-to type="org.elasticsearch.client.Client"/>
            </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexContent>
                <xsd:extension base="beans:identifiedType">
                    <xsd:attribute name="local" type="xsd:boolean" default="false">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>
                                <![CDATA[local here means local on the JVM (well, actually class loader) level, meaning that two local servers started within the same JVM will discover themselves and form a cluster]]>
                            </xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:attribute>
                    <xsd:attribute name="cluster-name" type="xsd:string" default="elasticsearch">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>
                                <![CDATA[Name of the cluster in which this instance of node client will connect to]]>
                            </xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:attribute>
                    <xsd:attribute name="http-enabled" type="xsd:boolean" default="true">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>
                                <![CDATA[ to enable or desable http port ]]>
                            </xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:attribute>
                </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:complexContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="transport-client">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation />
            <xsd:appinfo>
                <tool:assignable-to type="org.elasticsearch.client.Client"/>
            </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexContent>
                <xsd:extension base="beans:identifiedType">
                    <xsd:attribute name="cluster-nodes" type="xsd:string" default="127.0.0.1:9300">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>
                                <![CDATA[The comma delimited list of host:port entries to use for elasticsearch cluster.]]>
                            </xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:attribute>
                    <xsd:attribute name="cluster-name" type="xsd:string" default="elasticsearch">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>
                                <![CDATA[Name of the cluster in which this instance of node client will connect to]]>
                            </xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:attribute>
                    <xsd:attribute name="client-transport-sniff" type="xsd:boolean" default="true">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>
                                <![CDATA[The client allows to sniff the rest of the cluster, and add those into its list of machines to use.]]>
                            </xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:attribute>
                    <xsd:attribute name="client-transport-ignore-cluster-name" type="xsd:boolean" default="false">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>
                                <![CDATA[Set to true to ignore cluster name validation of connected nodes. (since 0.19.4)]]>
                            </xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:attribute>
                    <xsd:attribute name="client-transport-ping-timeout" type="xsd:string" default="5s">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>
                                <![CDATA[The time to wait for a ping response from a node. Defaults to 5s.]]>
                            </xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:attribute>
                    <xsd:attribute name="client-transport-nodes-sampler-interval" type="xsd:string" default="5s">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>
                                <![CDATA[How often to sample / ping the nodes listed and connected. Defaults to 5s.]]>
                            </xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:attribute>
                </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:complexContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

2) Store it in /webapp/META-INF/

3) Reference it in schemaLocation and work with his definitions normally.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:es="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch"
       xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch
                            META-INF/elasticsearch-1.0.xsd">

    <es:repositories base-package="com.project.repositories" />

    <es:transport-client id="searchClient" cluster-nodes="localhost:9300" />

    <bean name="elasticsearchTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="client" ref="searchClient"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

Having stumbled across this issue myself recently, i have a workaround which isn't pretty (and doesn't use the elasticsearch namespace), but does use the wrapped FactoryBean object).

Firstly remove the xmlns and schemaLocation references to the elasticsearch xsd and then reference the TransportClientFactoryBean as a bean:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <!-- Elasticsearch client -->
  <bean id="esClient" class="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.TransportClientFactoryBean">
    <property name="clusterNodes" value="localhost:9300" />
    <property name="clusterName" value="mycluster" />
  </bean>
```

Now you can use esClient bean as a TransportClient

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my solution was to fix the incompability in the xsd file, and place it in the resource directory, and reference it with classpath instead of http.

Comment: Could you share this an an answer? Specifically how you "reference it with classpath instead of http". I'm sure other's will find it useful

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dani, that works. Recently the fix has been applied to by Artur.

Refer: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-103.

So till the next version is out, you could use as below:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch https://jira.spring.io/secure/attachment/22773/spring-elasticsearch-1.0-fixed.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```